# small stop sign at the right bottom of the file (solution explorer VS2005)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-sourcesafe, solution-explorer

tried to find the answer by googling and in MSDN but with no luck.

what does a small stop sign mean in the icon of the file (seein in a soluton explorer tree) in Visual Studio. I have a bunch of C++ files with the thing and it really worrries me.

All these files are under source control and checked-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question screams for a screenshot. Are you seeing [one of these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181372%28VS.80%29.aspx)?